# Segment Data in Python

Tags: python

I want to segment my data based on variable `SEGMENT`. I have tried the following but it's not working. I want to segment if `SEGMENT` is either 70 or 80.

| Date | APPLICATION | SEGMENT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20180101 | 010101 | 60.0 |
| 20180102 | 010102 | 80.0 |

```
prive = df[df['SEGMENT'] == '70.0' | df['SEGMENT'] == '80.0']
```

Comment: the issue may just be that you're comparing against strings `'1.0'` instead of floats `1.0`! check the data type of the `"SEGMENT"` column with `df.dtypes`

Comment: What do you mean by "Not work". Are you getting an error or results other than what you expect? What is the `dtype` of your `SEGMENT` column?

Comment: Hi I have resolved it. Type was float, which is fine becuase it might contain letters as well (data quality issues). Was missing brackets :)
prive = df[(df['SEGMENT'] == '70.0') | (df['SEGMENT'] == '80.0')].copy()

Answer (score 0):

For Pandas multiple conditions you just need brackets round each condition:
prive = df[(df['SEGMENT'] == 70.0) | (df['SEGMENT'] == 80.0)]

I'm assuming SEGMENT values are floats not strings.

Comment: Hey LGH, you can turn the text into code blocks by selecting it and pressing CRTL K